# How to convert an array whose constructor is type String to a regular array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I have a string of `items` that looks like this:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

I run

```
>typeof items
Object

>items.constructor
function String()
```

and I'm trying to loop through the objects but I can't figure out if there is a way to convert the string to an array with some built in function.

Comment: Perhaps it is JSON, but typeof should give you string... How are you getting this string? Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: `var arr = JSON.parse("[{},{},{}]");`

Comment: `typeof` never returns an uppercase value. Please show us what you actually got, and how you were constructing that `items` variable.

Comment: You didn't do `new String` somewhere, did you? Just `arr = JSON.parse(items)` it nonetheless.